# SAPUI5 FileUploader: Cannot find and append file to FormData()

Tags: javascript, file-upload, sapui5, form-data

How do I access the file that I select with my fileuploader?

Any solutions are welcome.

```
var oInput = new sap.m.Input();  
var oFileUploader = new sap.ui.unified.FileUploader();

var oButton = new sap.m.Button({
text: "Send data",
press: function(){

    var oFormData = new FormData();

    oFormData.append("myTitle", oInput.getValue());
    oFormData.append("myFile", ****This is where I want to insert my file****);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
      xhr.open('POST', 'www.myUrl.com/foo/bar', true);
      xhr.send(oFormData);

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

```
oFileUploader.setUploadOnChange(true);

    var oFormData = new FormData();

    oFormData.append("title", "I am the title");

    jQuery.sap.domById(oFileUploader.getId() + "-fu").setAttribute("type", "file");
    oFormData.append("document", jQuery.sap.domById(oFileUploader.getId() + "-fu").files[0]);

    jQuery.ajax( {
      url: "www.myWebsite.com/path",
      data: oFormData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {

      },
      error: function() {

      }
    });
```

Comment: hi, can you please explain this part - jQuery.sap.domById(oFileUploader.getId() + "-fu").setAttribute("type", "file");
    oFormData.append("document", jQuery.sap.domById(oFileUploader.getId() + "-fu").files[0]);

Comment: Hi, the answer is a little late, but better late than never: first you set the type of the fileuploader to 'file' with jQuery. Subsequently, you attach that very content, which is then a file, to your FormData